# Merging of two files in shell

Tags: linux, shell, merge

I have tried the following command to merge two text files (AB_01.txt with xx_01.fasta, AB_02.txt with xx_02.fasta like that many files) and repeat the same process for other files.
Instead of many output for corresponding files, it generate  one correct output file for the last corresponding file of AB_030 with xx_030.
Where I should change command to generate output for all the files?

```
 for i in /path to file/AB_0*; 
    do for n in /path to file/xx_0*;
    do cat "$i"  "$n" > AX_0*.fas;
    done; done
```

Comment: Please click `edit` under your question, select your code with the mouse and click `{}` in the formatting toolbar beside **Bold** and *Italic* to format it as code. Or just indent all code by 4 spaces from the left. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer from another post.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.txt; do
    b=${i%%.txt}
    cat "$i" "$b".fasta >"$b".fas
done
```

Comment: Your code looks basically ok but does not match your question at all, i.e. "(to merge) AB_01 with xx_01, AB_02 with xx_02". Here you are merging anything.txt with anything.fasta into anything.fas. Either fix your question or your answer.